# Retrieving Data from multiple form field in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have have a form element like this

```
input type='text' name='phone[]'
input type='text' name='phone[]'
input type='text' name='phone[]'
```

How do i retrieve all three name element using PHP.
Thank you.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST)` in the receiving script and you will see.

Comment: Or a `print_r($_GET)` if your HTML form uses `method="get"`

Comment: @Pekka I need to get everything and put them in different variable, pls look at the code again, need to get something like $phone1,$phone2 etc. Thank

Comment: @Cyberomin what exactly is your question? Are you familiar with the basics of dealing with a form in PHP?

Comment: @Pekka from my question above i have input fields like this input type='text' name='phone[]'
input type='text' name='phone[]', how do i get the data into seperate variable using php, i cant do foreach($_POST['phone'] as $phone){}, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

when you do

```
$phones = $_POST['phone'];
```

you will get an array of "phones"

per your comment above you can have them in different variables by doing:

```
$phones[0]
$phones[1]
$phones[0]
```

Comment: go go go choose it as answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have your HTML form post to your PHP file, then get the values by:

Load the post array into a variable
    
`$phones = $_POST['phone'];`
Then pulling each value from the array

```
$phones[0];
$phones[1];
$phones[2];
...
```